# Cannot get receipt data

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am implementing the discount code feature and we use the following code to show the redeem sheet.

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
```

After redemption, I have to show the information about the discount code redemption and I know I can get that information by checking the receipt data.
To get the receipt data after applying the discount, I use the following code.

```
if let url = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL, 
   let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
      let receiptBase64 = data.base64EncodedString()
      print(receiptBase64)
}
```

Here, data is always nil. What's wrong here?
I'm testing this feature on real devices.

The URL is: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/StoreKit/sandboxReceipt

Comment: If there's no local receipt, make a request for it. See [Choosing a receipt validation technique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I used the wrong code to finalize the transaction.

Wrong code:

```
func purchase(_ product: Product) async throws -> StoreKit.Transaction? {
    let result = try await product.purchase()
    switch result {
        case .success(let verification):
            let transaction = try checkVerified(verification)
            await transaction.finish() // I thought when this code runs the receipt data is generated but it doesn't.
            return transaction
        case .userCancelled, .pending:
            return nil
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

func checkVerified<T>(_ result: VerificationResult<T>) throws -> T {
    switch result {
        case .unverified:
            throw StoreError.failedVerification
        case .verified(let safe):
            return safe
        }
    }
}
```

Fix:  `SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(SKPaymentTransaction)` should be called.

```
extension IAPManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction) // This is correct.
                break
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .deferred, .purchasing:
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I see the receipt data!

Comment: I'm having trouble with your wording. Are saying your mistake was in the use of modern StoreKit code when you should have been using old StoreKit code, or are you saying the opposite? In other words, should your answer say *"I was mistakenly using:"* instead of *"Wrong code"* and *"Instead, I needed to use `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`."* instead of *"Instead, I used the code to use `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`."* ?